# MongoLab Authentication Failed

Tags: java, spring-mvc, heroku, mlab

I have uploaded my Web application into Heroku and I have an add-on called, "MongoLab". I put the credentials of MongoLab into my Spring XML file and when I run it, I get an error:

```
{"message":"Failed to authenticate to database [heroku_c82w85xw], username = [heroku_c82w85xw], password = [k************************c]","code":"org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException
```

So I also made a Java Configuration file that holds the credentials, but I still get the same error. I have been trying for weeks, but I still get the same error. The following are my Spring XML and Java Configuration files.

Spring XML File:

```
    <mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="ds055575.mongolab.com" port="55575"/>

<mongo:db-factory 
    id="mongoDbFactory"
    host="ds055575.mongolab.com"
    port="55575"
    username="heroku_c82w85xw"
    password="XXX"
    dbname="heroku_c82w85xw"
    mongo-ref="mongo"/>

<bean id="anotherMongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />  
</bean>

<bean id="userDaoImpl" class="service.UserDaoImpl">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoOps" ref="anotherMongoTemplate" />
</bean>
<bean id="userService" class="service.UserService">
    <property name="userDaoImpl" ref="userDaoImpl" />
</bean>
```

Java Configuration File:

```
@Configuration
public class JavaConfig {
    public MongoClient getDB() {
        String uri = "mongodb://heroku_c82w85xw:XXX"
                + "@ds055575.mongolab.com:55575/heroku_c82w85xw?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1";
        MongoClientURI mongoURI = new MongoClientURI(uri);
        MongoClient client = null;
        try {
            client = new MongoClient(mongoURI);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return client;
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me with this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you solved this problem yet? I met the same problem, and also tried for days. If you have solved this problem, please write your answer below your question. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have solved it. I also had to put my credentials in my DAO constructor to be able to apply CRUD (create, read, update, and delete) to the database. Otherwise it will say "Failed to Authenticate".

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hard coding the URI, you should extract it from the environment variable that MongoLab sets for you. Here is an example:

```
String uri = System.getenv("MONGOLAB_URI");
MongoClientURI uri  = new MongoClientURI(uri); 
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri);
DB db = client.getDB(uri.getDatabase());
```

This is what MongoLab recommends in it's [documentation](http://docs.mongolab.com/languages/).

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I tried using System.getenv("MONGOLAB_URI") but when I printed it out, it gave me a null. I was looking into making environment variables, but the system did not recognize it. I will try it again and see what happens.

Comment: Are you running this locally or on Heroku? You will need to set the local env var manually.

Comment: I added the code from above and deployed it in Heroku, and it still says the same error: "Failed to authenticate to database [heroku_c82w85xw]".